# Two affectations and a test in if condition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm studying the highly optimized code of voronoi implementation by Mike Bokstok (d3js).

I don't understand the current test:

```
if (!(m = (halfedges = cell.halfedges).length)) return;
```

See the code here: https://github.com/d3/d3-voronoi/blob/master/src/Diagram.js#L87

1. halfedges and m are variables defined the line after! How can it work?
2. What is the purpose of the test? Is it defensive test if someone call the function using a wrong type of cell (without an halfedges property of type array)?

Answer (score 5):

Because of [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), `var` can be placed anywhere in a function but will be processed first in their scope:

```
bla = 2;
var bla;

// is implicitly understood as:
var bla;
bla = 2;
```

Note that it's using `=`, not `==`. It is not a test on `m` and `halfedges`, it is two affectations and a test on `cell.halfedges.length`.

It could be rewritten as

```
if (!cell.halfedges.length) return;
halfedges = cell.halfedges;
m = halfedges.length;
```

Comment: Ok, but it was not the questions.

Comment: 1) it can work because it's assigning the variables, not checking their values, and [var are processed first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) 2) if length == 0, do nothing

Comment: @GaetanZ Well, it *does* answer #1 of your questions pretty well. In addition to that it partially answers #2 by breaking it down into the test and the assignments. It is just a shortcut to skip the rest of the iteration for cells having an empty `halfedges` array. Like you already mentioned yourself: it is optimized code.

Comment: @altocumulus answer was edited to add var hoisting information

Comment: Sorry but I'm not going to accept the answer like that. There were two questions 1. and 2. I wanted to edit the answer to clearly show the answers (1. and 2.) that are in comments. But it was rejected by @shawn-mehan. I don't know why.